# Call to undefined function Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\simplexml_load_file()

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, centos

I am using Symfony2 and I am deploying my web to a CentOs6 server. I got this exception

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined function Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\simplexml_load_file() in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/XmlDriver.php line 736
```

What did I miss ? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

looks like for some reason you don't have the `simplexml` extension installed in your php version.

Have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) for full details.

Answer (score 1):

on debian apache2 system

```
$ sudo apt install php-xml
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```